SQLExpress 2022 Installation fails with the error "folder 'C:\SQL2022\Express_ENU\[DirSharedForCurrentVersion]' does not exist."
The following error has occurred:
The folder 'C:\SQL2022\Express_ENU\[DirSharedForCurrentVersion]' does not exist. The folder is expected to exist to set permission on it.

The installation fails near the end of the installation process. I have taken the following steps:

Ensured that I run setup.exe with Admin privledges
I have uninstalled my previous attempts (at least 5 of them)
I have run UnInstaller Pro and removed not only left-over files but left-over registry entries (of which there were many) after each uninstall.
Moved the setup folder to the D drive
Consumed much coffee
Rebooted and tried again

I don't believe I am the first with this issue because my google search turned up two instances of the same in installing SQLExpress 2019. Despite the installer submitting the much sought after logs, the MS Expert responder gave up and the installer must have subsequently passed away.
There is a subsequent error if I continue instead of cancel that refers me back to the original error. I don't think either has to do with privileges as it to refers to a folder directory which has the last entry again contained within brackets. I think that the folders are not being created but that of course could be privilege problems.
All suggestions on how to fix will be welcomed.
Edit Day3:

Tried above a couple more times with minor changes each time.
Clicking the Help button on each error screen takes me to the "Connect your SQL Server to Azure Arc" Learn Microsoft page. I don't have an Azure account and untick the reference to connecting to Azure each time.
Installed SQLExpress 2019 without any errors at all (at least I now have an instance working!)
Temporarily disabled UAC

